# Finding the first non-Nil element in an array

Tags: ruby

I have this code:

```
default_group_id =  @group_list[0].list[0].name
```

But sometimes the list member of `@group_list[0]` is empty so my code crashes :)
So I need to find the first `@group_list[i]` that its list member is not nil and use that.
How can we do this?

Here is the structure:

[image]

Comment: Just loop through the list. What's stopping you?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find):

```
@group_list.find { |x| !x["list"].blank? }
#=> first non-nil and non-empty list in group_list
```

Comment: sorry didn't work, still the same issue. I updated my question with the structure I am accessing. Hopefully that clarifies more my question. Thanks.

Comment: Note that `find{|x|x}` will reject nil and *false*, although it doesn't pertain to this question.

Comment: Note also that [`Object#blank?` is a Rails extension](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F) and is not part of the Ruby core language; again, not sure if this pertains to OP.

Answer (score 23):

`Enumerable#find` with passed `Object#itself` is a handy shortcut:

```
@group_list.find(&:itself)
```

Comment: this is witchcraft

Comment: Doesn't find falsey values though. Usually this is fine, but it's not strictly answering the question.

Comment: But how does this work?

Comment: @DenysAvilov `itself` method returns the object itself. `find` searches for the first element in an enumerable for which passed function returns truthy value, which means value that is not `nil` or `false`. `&:itself` is the same as `{ |obj| obj.itself }`. So `find` searches for the first non-`nil` non-`false` value in the enumerable.

Comment: @kolen thanks for the explanation! I'm kinda new to Ruby and got stuck with this construct I saw in my colleague's code. I honestly doubt it's a good idea to use such magic shortcuts even though they seem neat and smart, as it might impact readability for others...

Answer (score 7):

You could use [`Enumerable#find`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find):

```
@group_list.find{|x|!x.nil?} # => the first non-nil element in @group_list
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively:

```
@group_list.compact.first
```

Answer (score 0):

Using modern Ruby syntax:

```rb
@group_list.find { !_1.nil? }
```

If you don't care about **false** values:

```rb
@group_list.find { _1 }
```